# WCF - EmitDefaultValue without DataMemberAttribute

Tags: wcf, serialization

I'm using attribute-free DataContract serialization (.NET 3.5 SP 1).

I want change `EmitDefaultValue` to `false` for all my DataContracts.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the [`EmitDefaultValue` property on the `DataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx) that you apply to a property, then you will have to apply the `DataContractAttribute` to the type.

This has the unfortunate side-effect of having to place the `DataMemberAttribute` attribute on all members of the type that you wish to serialize (the ones you were assuming before you used attribute-free Data Contract serialization) due to the nature of Data Contract serialization being all-in when using the attributes.

Comment: I know about this side-effect, but i don't want to put DataMemberAttribute in every member of DataContracts. i wanna change the default value of EmitDefaultValue to false, can be in runtime (like a behavior)

Comment: @tiahgow: That's the point, the answer is you *can't* change that through config or runtime; currently the only items available through configuration for serialization is for setting known types.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing [`ISeriaizable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx).

In this case, `DataContractSerializer` will call your code to perform the mapping, giving you complete control.